# ReactJS - Fetch returns undefined on device (chrome)

Tags: reactjs, mobile, fetch, subdomain, device

English is not my main language so I will try to explain myself (sorry).

I have a website developed in ReactJS that works perfectly on a subdomain called "**test**": https://test.mydomain.com

All the URL's that call the api point to another subdomain called "**api**", for example: https://api.mydomain.com

In the desktop browser it works perfectly. But when I test in the device's browser (Chrome) the api always returns "undefined".

I copy part of my code:

At https://test.mydomain.com:

```
const myFuction= async() => {
    try {
      const API_ENDPOINT = `https://api.mydomain.com/users.php`;
      
const data = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          param1: "PARAM_1",
        }),

        
      });
      
const users = data.json();

      
      if (users.result.user != undefined) {
        
        console.log("Token OK");

        return true;
      } else {
        console.log("Token ERROR.");
        
        return false;
      }
      
    } catch (error) {
      
      alert(error);
      console.error(error);
    }

    return "ERROR";
  };
```

Could you help me? I've been trying to figure it out for days.

Thanks!

I solved the problem with the help of @punjira. The error was from CORS.
To solve it I had to add this line in the backend response:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

And I commented the headers that I sent in the request, the function looks like this:

```html
const myFuction= async() => {
     try {
       const API_ENDPOINT = `https://api.mydomain.com/users.php`;

      const data = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT, {
         method: "POST",
         // headers: {
         // Accept: "application/json",
         // "Content-type": "application/json",
         // },
         body: JSON.stringify({
           param1: "PARAM_1",
         }),


      });

      const users = data.json();


       if (users.result.user != undefined) {

         console.log("Token OK");

         return true;
       } else {
         console.log("Token ERROR.");

         return false;
       }

     } catch (error) {

       alert(error);
       console.error(error);
     }

     return "ERROR";
};
```

Comment: just guesing but if your code works fine on desktop and not on mobile maybe the problem is not with the react side. try logging some data with chrome remote debugging (you can fin it in `chrome://inspect/#devices`)

Comment: @punjira Thanks for your answer, I did the test with devTools and the errors are:

**Access to fetch at 'https://api.mydomain.com/users.php' from origin 'https://test.mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

And: 
**TypeError: Failed to fetch**